# Installing Gulp with nvm fails

Tags: npm, nvm

I'm a little stumped with this one. Same problem if I try to install -g. The package.json file is empty so not really sure.

```
{21:32}~/dev/repo/fo-website ➭ npm install gulp
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/leejohnson/.nvm/versions/v0.12.7/bin/node" "/Users/leejohnson/.nvm/versions/v0.12.7/bin/npm" "install" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! file /Users/leejohnson/.npm/clone/1.0.2/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! No data, empty input at 1:1
```

Comment: try running `npm init` to get a real package file. That could be a problem

Comment: I'm sure `npm init` might solve the problem but I'm also trying to figure out why I have this problem in the first place. I've built many NodeJS projects and installed dozens and dozens of packages across all these projects and I've never had a problem. The only thing that's changed is that I've added 0.12.7 recently via NVM. But even if I switch to previous version I still cannot install Gulp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was simple enough: delete the package.json file. Not sure where it came from and why it was empty, but removing it solved the problem.